# Some videos won't transfer from Mac to iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, video

I have videos stored on my Mac (iMac 2019, OS 10.14.6) in Photos and I am using iTunes (12.9.5.5) to sync them to my iPad Pro (iOS 15.3.1, 9.7" 2017). Some don't sync even though they play fine in Photos app. I have tried a setting in Handbrake (Apple 1080p30 surround) to make the video clips iPad friendly, but that doesn't transfer. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried AirDrop?

Comment: While Airdrop will convert the videos when transferring, you can try e.g. SendAnywhere or Snapdrop.net which will transfer without conversion.

Comment: I tried AirDrop with 2 videos. 1 transferred and showed up in the Photos app and 1 did not. Thanks for the idea.